# Decimal parse en un input type=text

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

Bueno en un input llamado totaldailymax se ingresa un horario por ejemplo 23.50 o lo que sea pero siempre hablando de horario. (No se le puede poner un type=time ni nada parecido.)
Bueno trato de parsear un string que viene por ejemplo "24,00" me lo toma como "2400" y yo necesito que me lo tome como "24.00"

Ingresando cualquier cosa que no sea "," lo convierte bien, el problema es que el campo en la base de datos es de tipo Decimal entonces explota cuando hibernet hace la ejecución de la consulta con un "2400". 
Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

El input es un type text común, el problema es que cuando llega la hora de la verificación la "," no la convierte sino que la desaparece. Utilizo la siguiente funcion:

```
staticProjecdsSetting.TotalDailyMax = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_TotalDailyMax.Text) ? 0 : decimal.Parse(txt_TotalDailyMax.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Lo que quiero es que la , la convierta en .

```
Hibernate flusing: could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available]; SQL []; Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.  The statement has been terminated. --> FROM INNER-MOST Message -->Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.  The statement has been terminated.
```

El error de hibernet.

Comment: Pon tu configuración de nhibernate.

Comment: Cambia `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat` por `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat`

Comment: En el hibernet hace un insert común y corriente, dame un segundo que lo busco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo simplemente usa la siguiente funcion:

```
    public decimal TextoaDecimal(string s){
    var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
    clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
    clone.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
    // ejemplo string s = "1,14535765" o string s="1.141516";
    decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, clone);

    return d;
}
```

saludos

Comment: A pesar de que este método pueda funcionar, parece demasiado complejo cuando ya existen culturas que consideran la coma como separador decimal (por ejemplo la española).

Comment: Si se que ya esta establecido como contexto de la cultura pero este puede para cuestiones genericas, gracias ya corregi el metodo.

Comment: Si, por eso digo que la respuesta es correcta, solo señalaba que parece un poco complicarse las cosas cuando en general, `CurrentCulture` o crear la cultura `es-ES` sería suficiente :)

Comment: Lo que pasa es que es un sistema internacional, sólo debo modificarla en caso que se ingrese una coma en vez de un punto, por que en otros países se utiliza la coma

Comment: Probé con desactivarla pero en otros países la utilizan como separador de decimal

Comment: @Juampi en ese caso la solución creo que sería lo que te comenté. CurrentCulture debería tomar la cultura local del navegador, con lo que usaría el separador decimal de cada pais.

Comment: @Pikoh lo probé pero sigue tirando error hibernet.

Comment: Solucionado con esta funcion. Gracias !